# Need alternative to cursor for sql query. Currently takes too long

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (stuID int, courseID int,outputvalue decimal(9,5))

DECLARE @parm1 int, @parm2 int, @parm3 int, @parm4 int, @parm5 varchar(10)
, @parm6 datetime, @parm7 datetime, @parm8 datetime, @parm9 varchar(5),@parm10 char(1),@parm11 char(1)

DECLARE gradeCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR

SELECT
        3968585,
        reg.building,
        schd_ms.[section_key],
        schd_ms_session.course_session,
        CONVERT(nvarchar,reg.student_id), 
        '2012-07-01',
        '2013-06-30',
        REPLACE(convert(varchar, getdate(), 102),'.','-'),
        '%',
        'N',
        'Y'

    FROM    test.dbo.reg

    INNER JOIN schd_stu_course on schd_stu_course.student_id = reg.student_id
    INNER JOIN schd_ms on schd_stu_course.section_key = schd_ms.section_key
    JOIN schd_ms_session on schd_ms_session.section_key = schd_ms.section_key

    where schd_ms.school_year = '2013'

OPEN gradeCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM gradeCursor INTO 
@parm1,@parm2,@parm3,@parm4,@parm5,@parm6,@parm7,@parm8,@parm9,@parm10,@parm11

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


DECLARE @odecStudentAverage decimal(9,5)

EXECUTE [Test_Live].[dbo].[spi_GBCalcStudentAverage] @Parm1, @Parm2, @Parm3, @Parm4, @Parm5, @Parm6, @Parm7, @Parm8, @Parm9,@Parm10, @Parm11, @odecStudentAverage output

INSERT INTO #TempTable (stuID, courseID,outputvalue)
Select @Parm5, @Parm3, @odecStudentAverage

FETCH NEXT FROM gradeCursor INTO 
@parm1,@parm2,@parm3,@parm4,@parm5,@parm6,@parm7,@parm8,@parm9,@parm10,@parm11
END

CLOSE gradeCursor
DEALLOCATE gradeCursor




SELECT
        reg.student_id,
        reg.building,
        schd_ms.[course],
        schd_ms.[section_key],
        schd_ms.[description],
        '',
        '',
        schd_ms_session.CREDIT,
        schd_ms_session.START_PERIOD,
        schd_ms_session.END_PERIOD,
        schd_ms_session.ROOM_ID,
        schd_ms_session.PRIMARY_STAFF_ID,
        schd_ms_session.course_session,
        #TempTable .outputvalue

    FROM    test_live.dbo.reg

    INNER JOIN schd_stu_course on schd_stu_course.student_id = reg.student_id
    INNER JOIN schd_ms on schd_stu_course.section_key = schd_ms.section_key
    JOIN schd_ms_session on schd_ms_session.section_key = schd_ms.section_key
    JOIN #TempTable on reg.student_id = #TempTable .stuID AND schd_ms.[section_key] = #TempTable .courseID 

    where schd_ms.school_year = '2013'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to run a stored procedure that you can't change on a per-row basis, you're pretty much SOL. You're stuck with the cursor.

Depending on how many rows you stuff into it, you might want to consider changing your temp table `#TempTable` to a table variable `@TempTable`. That can improve performance, but there is a threshold table size at which performance will suddenly tank with a table variable.

Comment: True, smaller data sets are generally faster with table variables, larger with temp tables.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is to change your `spi_GBCalcStudentAverage` procedure into a table-valued UDF, if you can.  That would allow you to include it in a set-based query that would replace your cursor.

Unless you do that, you aren't going to be able to get rid of the cursor, since you can't call a stored procedure in a set-based query.

Comment: I unfortunately cant modify this DB, belongs to a client where I have limited rights.  I had read that there was a way to iterate through result sets without a cursor, was hoping it might be faster.  I really appreciate the input though.

Comment: @user1440675, you can use a while loop but that willnot be faster. YOur best bet is refactoring the sp, which you say you can't do, so you aer stuck with the poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to get the rights you need to refactor proerly or live with the poor performance and tell teh client why the perfomance cannot be improved.

You can refactor in two ways:

Rewrite the sp to accept a set of data as the input wiither through a varaible witha  comma delimted list or through the use of a tableinput variable (newer version of SQl server)

Or create a tablevalued function. If they can give you teh code to the sp, you can create the table valued function to use set theroy instead of row-by-agonizing-row calling of a proc. They mighte be more willing to let you create a new object than change one that other parts of teh application are useing.

However, the real key to all of this, is that it is never acceptable to expect you to create solutions without the rights you need to create or alter what needs to be altered to fix the problem. What the client has done is crippled you. It is as if you wanted the mechanic to fix your car, but you refuse to give him the keys to start the engine with. You can't produce professinal work until you are given the car keys.